# Very slow ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 12.04, ram, memory-usage

I have use  2GB With Dual Core Processor Computer, and install ubuntu 12.04, Even though the computer is running very slow, All time Show CPU Uses 100 %, and Memory Uses 100%.

So What should i do to speed up my computer.

Answer (score 2):

First, look at `gnome-system-monitor` for realizing what's going on. But I think You must install [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)(LXDE based Ubuntu). You can get much higher performance with it on 2GB RAM with a dual core processor.

The difference is just the look. You can run everything that works under default Ubuntu

Comment: It Mean to say ,** gnome-system-monitor**  CPU process is very high,  and i do not use ** Lubuntu** only use **Ubuntu**.

Comment: if you have the answer so please give me, otherwise no problem,

Comment: Its a Graphical System Monitor Open it and check which service or process taking high usage.

Comment: Run it via typing `gnome-system-monitor` and switch to _Process_ tab. And See which process is exploitting CPU (click %CPU collumn). Otherwise, you can see it via `top` command.

Comment: And I've used Lubuntu when I was using old laptop like yours, 2GB Ram, Dual Core.  I definetly recommend Lubuntu. I just warn you but of course it's your decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can give try to use *nmon* (Monitor Linux Performance) tools will help you more to reduce the system performance,

More help Full tools:

**lsof** - List Open Files

**Htop** – Linux Process Monitoring

You can try [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) Alternative [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org/) which is based on KDE desktop, I used it and Kubuntu so much faster than Ubuntu:

**Kubuntu** [page](http://kubuntu.org/):